# Should I be using something other than getResource().getStringArray() to populate a large array?

Tags: android

Following the Android [sample for populating a ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html), I query an array from my *strings.xml* using [Activity.getResource().getStringArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getStringArray(int)):

```
String [] mDefinitions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.definition_array);
```

The documentation for this method is pretty clear and I didn't expect to encounter any problems with it:

> Return the string array associated with a particular resource ID.

This approach worked as expected for small data sets. However, when I populated *strings.xml* with the full data set (close to 2000 entries), I find that the app crashed when it tried to load the resource.  I noticed this error in the console log:

> ReferenceTable overflow (max=512)

Playing around with the number of items in my *string-array* I confirmed that the error was reproducible when the number of items exceeded ~700 entries.

Googling the problem has turned up some examples of other developers [having the same problem](http://www.listware.net/201005/android-developers/4451-android-developers-max-size-of-string-array.html), but I can't find anything in the Android documentation to explain it.

Someone has gone to the trouble of creating an [issue for the problem](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5287) on the Android Google Code page but neither it, or any of the posts I came across, received a satisfactory answer.

Am I approaching the problem the wrong way? Should I be populating the data myself (loading a file and parsing JSON or similar) and avoid the issue entirely? It feels like I am missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I need to be able to parse large XML files for my particular application (I already had data encoded that way and I wanted to keep it consistant).

So my first attempt was to use *getStringArray*, which suffers from the problem described in the question:

```
String [] mDefinitions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.definition_array);
```

My second attempt suffers from the same limitation that I encounted with *getStringArray*. As soon as I tried processing a larger XML file (> 500K), I got a DalvikVM crash on *getXml*:

```
 XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.index);

 try {
     int eventType = parser.getEventType();

     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
         String name = null;

         switch (eventType){
             case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                 // handle open tags
                 break;
             case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                 // handle close tags
                 break;
         }

         eventType = parser.next();
     }
 }
 catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Cannot parse XML");
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Cannot parse XML");
 }
 finally {
     parser.close();
 }
```

My final solution, which uses the SAX parser on a *InputStream* generated from the raw resource works.  I can parse large XML files without the DalvikVM crashing:

```
 InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.index);
 XmlHandler myXMLHandler = new XmlHandler();

 SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
 SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
 XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

 xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
 xr.parse(new InputSource (is));

 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
 }
```

Where XmlHandler is:

```
 public class XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler {

     @Override
     public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
     Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
     // handle elements open
     }

     @Override
     public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
     throws SAXException {  
     // handle element close
     }

     @Override
     public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
     throws SAXException {
     // handle tag characters <blah>stuff</blah>
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whats the objective of your application but have you thought about using a csv file.

```
 InputStream is = c.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.csv_file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String readLine = null;

        int column = 1; 

        try {
            while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: @sameersegal So I guess your answer would be "yep, you should be loading the data yourself and avoiding the issue entirely" ;). I was certainly leaning in this direction. However, I do wonder why the documentation is so silent on the issue.