# How big can strings.xml resources be?

Tags: android, android-resources

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272828/android-development-string-array-resource-too-big-crashing-android-app) post that says when `strings.xml` gets too big the app may crash. My `strings.xml` file is 800 plus lines right now and it will be a lot bigger in a while.

The answers in the post say that using a SQLite database can prevent the crash.

But in my case I have a SQLite database that takes the data for the entries from `strings.xml` because my app uses locales for different languages.

My question is, how big can `strings.xml` be? And if I hit the line limit what can I do to prevent the crash?

Comment: What did your logcat says

Comment: as i said there is no a crash right now, but the post that i linked says if the strings.xml is to big the app will  be crash. My strings.xml will be to  big in a while, my question is how big can strings.xml can be ?

Comment: Why can't you use SQLite *directly*? Meaning one table for each language? Just choose the language table you need and use the strings stored inside that one.

Comment: @Fantômas because the app was designed from the beginning like this and we are using locale with strings resources. And it wants a lot of  work to  transfer  all the data from strings.xml in new tables. Maybe it will be done in a future refactoring!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limitation of the strings.xml. Its more a problem of loading a string array. The getResources().getStringArray function is not meant to load arrays with more elements than 512 (more about this here [Should I be using something other than getResource().getStringArray() to populate a large array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522181/should-i-be-using-something-other-than-getresource-getstringarray-to-populat)) But as long as you are not using big arrays you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `Resources.get***` methods doesn't have any explicit limitation, so it depends on your device's memory size. And as I know the old version of Android has [per process memory limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675557/what-is-the-maximum-amount-of-ram-an-app-can-use).

Comment: So that is not about how big strings.xml is ? but about the Resources.get***  method ?

Comment: Beacause my strings.xml file will be 1000+ lines. It is not a problem ?

Comment: Because you read strings.xml with Resources' methods. 1000+ lines in an xml file is not extravagant. You just need to take care of the memory usage.